# HTML code download link and not to open it in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I want to create a webpage where I want a link that causes any browser to only download the link and not open it irrespective of the format. Is it possible? If not plain HTML, then any other way?

Comment: You need to send the correct HTTP headers when serving the file. This can't be done in HTML! What server-side language(s) do you have available?

Answer (score 1):

I have this for downloading files - rather than a link to the file - it links to this php file running on a server. The php then returns the desired file  (i.e. it downloads).

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['filename']) exit;
<get the file from the file system>
header("Cache-Control: ");
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_POST['filename'].'"');
<echo ref to file>?>
```

Will probably need some modification for your specific purposes the /<.>/ are something like pseudo-code comments.
Cheers.